# jQueryMobile makes whole page clickable

Tags: events, jquery-mobile

I have to demonstrate the issue I'm experiencing on my Android phone a simple example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en"> 
    <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.0/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.css">

            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.js"><\/script>')</script>
            <script src="js/libs/jquery.mobile-1.1.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
            <div data-role="page" id="login">
                    <div data-role="content">
                        This is a TEST
                    </div><!-- /content -->
            </div><!-- /page -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Now when you load this in your android browser and tap somewhere on the page you will see the page highlight and a click sound. 
How annoying is that, I definitely want to turn that off, but is that possible ?

Cheers
Luca

Answer (score 0):

Put following in your head of HTML page.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```